# How can I find all the places a userid has permissions in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint

If an employee leaves the company we need a way to find all the places that person has been granted permission in SharePoint. And then of course we would need to remove those permissions or if they are a site owner, change the owner to another employee.

Has anybody done this or have an idea where to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently put together a web part to do this - basically, each `SPList` in each `SPWeb` on your site has a collection of `SPRoleAssignment` objects, which define the permissions for that object. Within the `SPRoleAssignment`, there is a collection of `Member` objects, from which you can get the name of the user or group that has been assigned permission to this object. This allows you to get the permissions even if the list or folder is not inheriting from a parent. The [Access Checker Web Part](http://www.codeplex.com/AccessChecker) mentioned earlier does this, but it does not look at sub-folders, which may have their own permissions.

The bottom line is that **if you have given users explicit permission to distinct folders**, you will need to either build a solution to give you a run-down of the permissions, or click through every folder separately. There is no built-in functionality to display this quickly and simply.

Answer (score 3):

We use [Sharepoint Access Checker Web Part](http://www.codeplex.com/AccessChecker) to check which sites a user has been granted permissions.

Answer (score 2):

This link may be useful...
[VBDotNetHeaven - Checking User Permissions in SharePoint Sites](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/ssahmed/spuserperm09192006044916AM/spuserperm.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super familiar with how SharePoint permissions work, but it is probably a best practice to not give any one employee direct access to anything and to use AD Security Groups.  When they leave the company, you can remove their profile and name from all AD Security Groups and not worry about access to anything including SharePoint.

I do know that you can view the SharePoint site permissions, but nested SharePoint sites can create more hassle.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't answer my question. I understand what you are saying but that is not how this company decided to do things.

Comment: From Site Actions in sharepoint, if you got to Site Settings, there is a like for Advanced Permissions.  From that screen, you should be able to look for their name.

Comment: I know this is years later but just found this thread... I think RSolberg likes to hear himself type... answer and comment are so off topic...

Comment: Valid... glad to see you learning! And obviously with your rep, it seems you are an avid contributor here. Thank you.

Comment: Learning?  No need to be a dick?  Back in the day that is how we did things.

Answer (score 0):

I manage our sharepoint site and use Active Directory to handle all the security.  I would recommend if you don't do that now to try to move to that type of security model.

Answer (score 0):

Click <kbd>Site Actions</kbd> → <kbd>Site Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Site Permissions</kbd> and it will show everyone who has individual access.  You can delete anyone you no longer with to have it.